# Find average runtime of arbitrary functions using decorators and number of calls

Tags: python, decorator

Create a function that decorates another function in the following way:

```
@profile
def foo ( ... ) :
    ...
```

What profile does is to record information about the runtime of, and the number of calls to the function it decorates using the clock function of the time module. For example:

```
from time import clock
start = clock()
    #do something for a while
duration = clock() - start
```

Your implementation of profile should only record the runtime of a function if a global variable `PROFILE_FUNCTIONS` has the value True. Regardless of the value of `PROFILE_FUNCTIONS`, your decorator should not change the behavior of the function it decorates. That is, the decorated function should accept the same number and kinds of parameters and output the same values as if it were not decorated. Your decorator must also be generic, i.e. I should be able to decorate arbitrary functions with profile.

Record the profiling results in a global dictionary `PROFILE_RESULTS`. The dictionary should map the profiled function names to the tuple: (a, b), in which a is the average runtime over all calls to the function and b is the number of times the function is called.

So far, I have:

```
import time  
import operator                                        
PROFILE_RESULTS={}
funcs_ran=[]
func_runtimes=[]
func_occurences=[]

def profile(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        startTime = clock()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        endTime = clock()-start
        funcs_ran.append(method.__name__)
        func_runtimes.append(endTime - startTime)

@profile
def func1(sleep):
    time.sleep(sleep)
```

I call it with:

```
func1(0.5)
func1(1)
func1(2)
```

So far I have the functions and runtimes but I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: How to calculate the averages and store the appropriate data in PROFILE_RESULTS

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it. I got rid of most of the globals and changed the one left into a dictionary. This makes updating it and checking for membership both fast and fairly easy. That included eliminating `PROFILE_RESULTS` because I'm not sure what you want put in it.

Note that your decorator function was incorrectly coded—it never returned the decorated function/method (which itself needs to return the results of calling the original).

```
import time

func_runtimes = {}

def profile(method):
    """ Profiling decorator. """
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        start_time = time.clock()

        result = method(*args, **kw)

        elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
        func_runtimes.setdefault(method.__name__, []).append(elapsed_time)
        return result
    return wrapper  # Decorated method (need to return this).

def print_stats(method_name):
    if method_name not in func_runtimes:
        print("{!r} wasn't profiled, nothing to display.".format(method_name))
    else:
        runtimes = func_runtimes[method_name]
        total_runtime = sum(runtimes)
        average = total_runtime / len(runtimes)
        print('Stats for method: {!r}'.format(method_name))
        print('  run times: {}'.format(runtimes))
        print('  total run time: {}'.format(total_runtime))
        print('  average run time: {}'.format(average))

@profile
def func1(sleep):
    time.sleep(sleep)

func1(0.5)
func1(1)
func1(2)

print('func_runtimes:', func_runtimes)
print()
print_stats('func1')
```

Output:

```
func_runtimes: {'func1': [0.4996212506738944, 1.0000399133651898, 2.0000319306921517]}

Stats for method: 'func1'
  run times: [0.4996212506738944, 1.0000399133651898, 2.0000319306921517]
  total run time: 3.499693094731236
  average run time: 1.166564364910412
```

Comment: @coder: You could rename the `func_runtimes` variable `PROFILE_RESULTS` if that makes you happy.